# CiviDiscount multiple purchase discount

Tags: cividiscount

I have 3 events that I would like to offer a 15% discount to any user that purchases all three. I've found how to do this with Woocomerce by doing some googling but I have yet to find a method for CiviDisocount to do anything similar. It would be greatly appreciated for any sort of assistance. Thank you

Roy

Comment: Perhaps check the integration with Caldera Forms, see if it is possible to let a user choose which events to register on the one form, then use Conditionals or code to change the price/total if they choose all 3